# Why is figuring out if the cardinality of a language is not finite a "decidable" problem?

Tags: automata

Given two finite-state languages L1 and L2, then determining their intersection is not finite is a decidable problem.

How can this be? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let M1 and M2 be minimal deterministic finite automata whose accepted languages are L1 and L2, respectively.

First, construct a deterministic finite automaton M3 whose accepted language is the intersection of L1 and L2 by using the Cartesian Product Machine construction - an algorithm which produces the desired machine.

Next, construct a deterministic finite automaton M4 which accepts the same language as M3, but which is minimal; that is, minimize M3 and call the result M4. There is an algorithm which produces this result.

Next, construct a deterministic finite automaton M5 which accepts only words of length strictly greater than k, where k is the number of states in M4. There is such a machine with k+1 states for any alphabet; its construction is not complicated.

Next, construct a deterministic finite automaton M6 whose accepted language is the intersection of the languages accepted by M4 and M5. Use the Cartesian Product Machine construction again here.

Next, construct a deterministic finite automaton M7 by minimizing M6.

At this point, either M6 is a deterministic finite automaton with one state which accepts no strings at all, or not. In the former case, the intersection of L1 and L2 is finite; in the latter case, that intersection is infinite. Why?

1. M1 accepts L1
2. M2 accepts L2
3. M3 accepts L1 intersect L2
4. M4 is a DFA accepts L1 intersect L2 and has as few states as possible
5. M5 accepts only words which would cause M4 to enter one of its states twice
6. M6 accepts only words in L1 intersect L2 that also cause M4 to enter one of its states twice. Note that if M6 accepts anything, that means there are words in L1 intersect L2 which a minimal DFA for that language must loop to accept; because such a loop could be followed any number of times, this implies there must be infinitely many words in L1 intersect L2. This is closely related to the pumping lemma for regular languages.
7. M7 accepts what M6 does, but is minimal. Note that minimization is not necessary but it makes it trivial to check whether M6 accepts anything or not. The minimal DFA which accepts no string has one dead state. This is easy to check, and there are standard algorithms for minimization.

Another similar way of showing the same thing would be to say you can construct the DFA for the intersection and then check all strings of length from |Q| to |2Q|. No finite language will have any strings of these lengths accepted by a DFA for that language, but every infinite language will have at least one such string. This is because any DFA accepting an infinite language must loop, and the length of that loop must be no greater than the number of states.